# Can't type full Korean syllable blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can usually type in Korean just fine by myself in any other game or website, but on minecraft it ends up looking like this if I try to type any word/syllable;

ㅇㅜㅇㅠ when it should be 우유, or ㅇㅗㄴㅡㄹ when it should be 오늘, for example. I have the correct input on my mac, but nothing seems to be working on minecraft, and it becomes very frustrating when talking to Korean friends since I have to copy and paste from a sticky note or something else. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

<sub>MoonWolf's answer, originally posted as a comment:</sub>

---

It doesn't happen with 1.14.2

Even though I don't like the newer versions, I guess I'll just have to use it for now. I originally tried 1.12.2 before the new update and it didn't work then so I guess I never bothered to try it with the new version.